# How can I make a SharePoint site inside a VM not ask users on the host for credentials?

Tags: virtual-machine, sharepoint, iis-6

I have Windows Server 2003 installed in a virtual machine with Windows XP Pro as a host. Inside of the VM, I have SharePoint 2007 running on IIS 6.0. Inside the virtual machine, I can get to the SharePoint site I made just fine, but when I try to access my website from the host, it asks me for a username and password, even though I have anonymous access enabled. 
How can I eliminate that username/password request?

Comment: Is the Guest account enabled in WS2003 ?

Comment: No, it is not. Should it be?

Answer (score 1):

For XP to authenticate itself on WS2003 as anonymous, the guest account must be enabled, since anonymous translates into guest.

A better solution would be to create an account on WS2003 that has the same name as the account on the XP and grant it the necessary permissions.